# ASP.NET WebForms : Unable to find ArcGISRuntime deployment folder (on server)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, deployment, webforms, arcgis

I have a simple .NET WebForms application with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET 10.2.6.0 installed on the development machine running MS Visual Studio Professional 2013.

When I run my ASPX page locally, no issues. But when trying to do the same on the web server where I copied the project via FTP, I get the following runtime server error:

***Error initializing ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment. Unable to find ArcGISRuntime deployment folder. To create a deployment run the ArcGISRuntime Deployment Tool to create a folder called arcgisruntime10.2.6***

---

ArcGIS deployment folder VS is using on the development machine is probably within the GAC :

*C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS SDKs\DotNet10.2.6\WindowsDesktop\bin\arcgisruntime10.2.6*

---

I uploaded ArcGIS DLL & deployment folder on the server via FTP as follows:

*/site/wwwroot/bin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.dll*

*/site/wwwroot/bin/arcgisruntime10.2.6/*

*/site/wwwroot/bin/arcgisruntime10.2.6/client32/*

*/site/wwwroot/bin/arcgisruntime10.2.6/client64/*

ASP.Net page I run is at the root:

*/site/wwwroot/TestPage.aspx*

and the business logic CS file at:

*/site/wwwroot/Content/Geometry.cs*

---

So where the ArcGIS deployment folder has to be created if not in the /bin ? Also are client32 & client64 enough to avoid the runtime error, knowing that I haven't copied LocalServer and resources subfolders? Perhaps I should change ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.InstallPath but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The runtime SDK can't be used for server side applications as it's against the licensing requirements. You need to switch to using ArcGIS Server or Portal.

Comment: That makes sense, but can you show us reference?. I am in particular not sure what SDK to we use instead.. (I don't see ArcGIS Server SDK or ArcGIS Portal SDK)

Comment: There isn't really a standalone SDK for those as they are included with each version of an SDK for a particular technology. See developers.arcgis.com for the available SDKs. They all work on top of the REST API (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/The_ArcGIS_REST_API/02r300000054000000/) though so you can always write your own code to reference that if you need.